# Search and display multiple columns when using jquery autocomplete in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have successfully integrated Jquery-Autocomplete into my rails app, currently users can search more than 5000+ airports and so far the integration works exactly as desired, however...

Any Airport has multiple columns, currently i am returning the airport name but would like to instead show

**

> airport_name - airport_city - airport_iata - airport_icao

**

I have so far used Ryan Bates Railscast to get me started 
[Episode #102](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised?view=comments)

But amended and tweaked thanks to other resources since his video. Sorry i can't reference them right now but will update my question once i've found links to their instructions.

Either way Autocomplete does work as designed and i have managed to populate a hidden field but i would really like to display more than just the Airport name when searching. I will continue to only save the airport ID.

Any help is appreciated, here is my code.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :departure_airport %><br>
  <%= text_field_tag nil, nil, :id => 'claim_departure_airport_name', data: {autocomplete_source: Airport.order(:name).map { |t| { :label => t.name, :value => t.id } } }, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<%= f.hidden_field :d_airport_id, id: 'd_airport_id' %>

<%= f.hidden_field :a_airport_id, id: 'a_airport_id' %>
```

**claims.coffee**

```
jQuery ->

$('#claim_departure_airport_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#claim_departure_airport_name').data('autocomplete-source')
    select: (event, ui) ->

        # necessary to prevent autocomplete from filling in
        # with the value instead of the label
        event.preventDefault()

        $(this).val ui.item.label
        $('#d_airport_id').val ui.item.value

$('#claim_arrival_airport_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#claim_arrival_airport_name').data('autocomplete-source')
    select: (event, ui) ->

        # necessary to prevent autocomplete from filling in
        # with the value instead of the label
        event.preventDefault()

        $(this).val ui.item.label
        $('#a_airport_id').val ui.item.value
```

As you can see i am directly reaching the model data without the need for a dedicated controller although i realise this would be much more intelligent than my current solution as i wish to roll this out in other areas of the platform.

I don't fully understand everything that is happening in the jquery code in my coffee file this was obtained from another source although i forget who to give credit. As far as i know it's taking the ID of the airport and populating the hidden field?

If you can spot how to show other airport database columns to the user that would be great.

Thanks

**edit**

Also wish to restrict autocomplete from loading the data source into html due to seriously long page load times. A screen shot of what i mean is below.

[screenshot of data loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7So6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the autocomplete source to

```
<%= text_field_tag nil, nil, id: 'claim_departure_airport_name', data: { autocomplete_source: Airport.select(:id, :name, :city, :iata, :icao).order(:name).map { |t| { label: "#{t.name}-#{t.city}-#{t.iata}-#{t.icao}", value: t.id } } }, class: "form-control" %>
```

To refactor this a bit, you can move the active record query into a helper

```
def airport_autocomplete_data
  Airport.select(:id, :name, :city, :iata, :icao).order(:name).map { |t| { label: "#{t.name}-#{t.city}-#{t.iata}-#{t.icao}", value: t.id } }
end
```

and your text field becomes

```
<%= text_field_tag nil, nil, id: 'claim_departure_airport_name', data: { autocomplete_source: airport_autocomplete_data }, class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I've used your initial suggestion and tested which seems to work well. I wondered if there was a way to stop the full contents of the source loading? There are 5,000+ airports to search and im loading them twice it seems so the page load time is expectedly very slow.

Ive updated my question to include a screen shot of what i mean. Thanks

Comment: Refer this - https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote. You need to create a new route which responds data in the required format. You can write active record filters there.

Answer (score 0):

The main point is here `data: {autocomplete_source: Airport.order(:name).map { |t| { :label => t.name, :value => t.id } } }`

It builds an array of objects, like `[{'label': 'BKK', value: 1}, {'label': 'HAM', value: 2}]`

So you either need to add something to the label key, or maybe add a different key and use it later in the `select` callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails4-autocomlete Gem. You can easily override from controller.

> ```
> def autocomplete_profile
>       term = params[:term]
>       profiles = Profile.where(
>         'LOWER(profiles.first_name) LIKE ? OR LOWER(profiles.last_name) LIKE ?',
>         "%#{term}%", "%#{term}%"
>         ).order(:id).all
>       render :json => profiles.map { |profile| {:id => profile.id, :label => profile.id, :value => profile.id} }
>     end
> ```